# Removeable Glass Bed vs. Removeable Springsteel Beds

Tags: heated-bed, build-plate, glass-bed

Removeable beds are starting to get more common in low-price consumer-grade printers. There are pretty much 3 types:

- Unheated beds
- Heated beds from steel held by magnets or clips
- Heated glass beds held by clips

Unheated beds are the lowest class, and not an issue here. **What are the pros and cons for a steel/springsteel bed versus a glass bed?**

Answer (score 2):

In favor of glass:

- Smoother surface gives you a nicer bottom layer (though Kapton-layered steel is no slouch)
- More even, regular surface makes bed easier to level
- Easy to prep and clean
- More scratch-resistant makes getting under a part with a metal scraper a little less harrowing
- Corrosion-resistant (glass doesn't rust; silicon dioxide is in fact already about as oxidized as it can possibly be)

In favor of steel:

- Flexes for easier release
- Safer (steel plates don't shatter, at least not at temperatures you're likely to use them)
- Conducts heat better for faster and more even heating
- Slightly less expensive on average

Comment: Surely slower conductivity means more even heating? That way the heat can dissipate more easily.

Comment: "at least not at temperatures you're likely to use them" bwahahahaha